# Customise train_step in model.fit() "OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function"

Tags: conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord, faster-rcnn

I am trying to write a custom train_step to use in the tf.keras.Model.fit() function. I am following  [tensor flow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/customizing_what_happens_in_fit). Here in the train_step function from what I understand the input argument data is supposed to be the training dataset that I am about to pass in Model.fit() function. My dataset is TFRecordDataset. My dataset gives three particular features i.e. image, labels and the box. So, in the train_step function i am first trying to get the img, labels and box parameters from the data argument that is passed.

```html
def train_step(self, data):
        print("printing data fed to train_step")
        print(data)
        img, label, gt_boxes = data
        if self.DEBUG:
            if(img == None):
                print("img input in train step is none")
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            rpn_classification, rpn_regression = self(img, training=True)
            self.tf_rpn_target_generation_layer(gt_boxes, rpn_regression)
            loss = self.rpn_loss_function(rpn_classification)
        
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)

        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))

        loss_tracker.update_state(loss)
        #mae_metric.update_state()
        return [loss_tracker]
```

The above is the code I use for my custom train_step function. When I run the fit, I get the following error
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.

I have used shuffle, cache, and repeat operations on my training dataset. Can anyone please help me understand why exactly this error appears?

From my previous experience, i generally create an iterator for the dataset followed by get_next operation to obtain the features.

Edit:
I have tried the following procedures but did not yield any outcome

1. Since the data being sent into the train_step is a dataset object, I have used tf.raw_ops.IteratorGetNext method to access the elements of the iterator which returned an error saying
   "TypeError: Input 'iterator' of 'IteratorGetNext' Op has type string that does not match the expected type of resource."
2. To fix this error, I have assumed that it was likely tensorflow returning iterator graph and hence unable to access the elements, so I have added run_eagerly=True argument to the model.compile() function which returned gibberish being printed and the same error.

```html
Epoch 1/5
printing data fed to train_step
Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(0,), dtype=int32)
Tensor("IteratorGetNext:0", shape=(), dtype=string)
```

Comment: i think indexing could also work

Comment: I have tried indexing and it didnot work. From what i understand the error might be related to the iterator object that is returned as the data when using model.fit. The error when further debugged using tf.raw_ops, i understood that the iterator object provided is string and hence tf.raw_ops.IteratorGetNext did not work as it isnt the expected input resource type.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. The data that is being passed to my step function is an iterator and hence I have to use tf.raw_ops.IteratorGetNext method to access the contents of the iterator.

When doing this I initially got another error saying that the iterator type does not match the expected type of resource and when debugged carefully I understood that the read_tfrecords mapping that I had to do to the dataset was unsuccessful and that lead to the dataset still containing unmapped tfrecords of format tf.string which is not an expected type of resource for the train_Step.